# How to close a class in java

Tags: java, class

I am busy making a 2D game. I have 1 class called Render that contains a JFrame. 
 This class calls Keying, which is the actual 2D game. When you lose, I cannot find how you close the Keying class which also contains the GUI.

```
public Render(Keying k, boolean Main) {
    Lost();
}
//k is the public variable for the Keying class
public void Lost() {
    new SetupGame();
    k.close();
}
```

The Keying class:

```
public void lost() {
    Render rend = new Render(this, false);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get valuable help from the community. Your code is not something that compiles and it's not obvious to understand how it would (example: where is `k` declared, how is it initialized, when is the `lost` method called?). It also appears to exist a cyclic dependency between `Render` and `Keying`. Hence it's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

first define a close() method inside Keying class.
After loosing the game Inside lost() method call the Keying's class close() method which further call the actual GUI's close() method which you want.